# Given a beginner PHP assignment, not entirely sure what this means

Tags: php

```
http://localhost:8888/test.php
```

I typed in the above URL to navigate to a blank php file I'd created, and my friend typed the following in my URL bar:

```
?one=3&two=18
```

(after /test.php)

He said that when I refresh the page, he wants to see the number 21 show up. I'm not entirely sure where to start. Any help for this PHP beginner is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['one']) AND isset($_GET['two'])) {

    $one = (int) $_GET['one'];

    $two = (int) $_GET['two'];

    echo $one + $two;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`?` is the operator used to indicate the start of the parameters passed to a webpage. You can pass many of them separated by the character `&`. Based on that you need your website to get those parameters and perform the only operation that will get you the result `21` from `18` and `3`.
So you need your webpage to display the sum of your first parameter and your second parameter. 
You can get those by using `$_GET`.

Bottom line what you need is:

1. [Learn how to get the parameters passed](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)
2. [Learn how to do operations with them (sum)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)
3. [Learn how to display the result.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)
4. [Learn about UrlEncode](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Good luck on the php world!

Comment: p.s: and remember, the url lenght should never be more than 2028 characters ;)

Comment: @Daniel Right, adding that one... :)

Comment: $_GET is not a function, it is an array which PHP populates for you.

Comment: @arex1337 Right! Used to the Java Get/Set being methods... and W3sChools didn't help a lot...  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to obtain something from your query string (?... part of the URL) you have to use $_GET[] i.e.

```
$one = $_GET['one'];
$two = $_GET['two'];
echo $one+$two; //print it
```

Comment: obv everything wrapped inside a <?php ... ?> :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to GET the variables from that URL and manipulate them.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp

But you first and foremost need to learn from the ground up. I suggest this tutorial:

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['one'] + $_GET['two'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`print_r($_GET)` will show you the anwser.